# How to customize jtree element?

Tags: java, jtree

I want to delete this black border around jtree element and remove white background from text. How to do it ?

In customize code tab i have this 3 lines. Where to start ?

```
jTree1 = new javax.swing.JTree();

jTree1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(213, 219, 226));

jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTree1);
```

Photo example from netbeans, what i want to do:

[image: Photo example from netbeans, what i want to do]